# TIFF images support in Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

Is the input TIFF images with Form recognizer Sample Label Tool supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set#general-input-requirements

Comment: Can you please share the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue and will be fixed soon. Until the fix is available and as a workaround you can convert the Tiff files to PDFs or images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is stated on the page you referenced. Are you having any issues regarding TIFF images in combination with the Label Tool?

> Format must be JPG, PNG, PDF (text or scanned), or **TIFF**. Text-embedded PDFs are best because there's no possibility of error in character extraction and location.